# Not able to extract All URL's from json Script using beautifulsoup3

Tags: python, json, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, export-to-csv

```
   import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json
import re

url = "https://www.daraz.pk/catalog/?q=dell&_keyori=ss&from=input&spm=a2a0e.searchlist.search.go.57446b5079XMO8"
page = requests.get(url)

print(page.status_code)
print(page.text)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
print(soup.prettify())



alpha = soup.find_all('script',{'type':'application/ld+json'})

jsonObj = json.loads(alpha[1].text)
```

### Below is the code to Find All the relevant product information from json object

```
for item in jsonObj['itemListElement']:
    name = item['name']
    price = item['offers']['price']
    currency = item['offers']['priceCurrency']
    availability = item['offers']['availability'].split('/')[-1]
    availability = [s for s in re.split("([A-Z][^A-Z]*)", availability) if s]
    availability = ' '.join(availability)
```

### Here is the code to extract URL for json script

```
    url = item['url']

print('Availability: %s  Price: %0.2f %s   Name: %s' %(availability,float(price), currency,name, url))
```

### Below is the code to extract data inro csv:

```
outfile = open('products.csv','w', newline='')
writer = csv.writer(outfile)
writer.writerow(["name", "type", "price", "priceCurrency", "availability" ])

alpha = soup.find_all('script',{'type':'application/ld+json'})

jsonObj = json.loads(alpha[1].text)

for item in jsonObj['itemListElement']:
    name = item['name']
    type = item['@type']
    url = item['url']
    price = item['offers']['price']
    currency = item['offers']['priceCurrency']
    availability = item['offers']['availability'].split('/')[-1]
```

### The File creates the Header but no data in CSV for the URL

```
writer.writerow([name, type, price, currency, availability, URL ])
outfile.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first, you don't include the header there. not a big deal, just the first row would have a blank for your header in the `url` column. So to include that:

```
writer.writerow(["name", "type", "price", "priceCurrency", "availability", "url" ])
```

Second, you store the string as `url`, but then reference `URL` in your writer. `URL` isn't holding any value. In fact, it should have given an error of `URL is not defined` or something similar.

And since you already use `url` in your code with `url = "https://www.daraz.pk/catalog/?q=dell&_keyori=ss&from=input&spm=a2a0e.searchlist.search.go.57446b5079XMO8"`, I would also probably change the variable name to something like `url_text`.

I'd probably also use variable `type_text` or something other than `type`, since `type` is a built-in function in python.

But you need to change to:

```
writer.writerow([name, type, price, currency, availability, url ])
outfile.close()
```

Full code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json
import csv

url = "https://www.daraz.pk/catalog/?q=dell&_keyori=ss&from=input&spm=a2a0e.searchlist.search.go.57446b5079XMO8"
page = requests.get(url)

print(page.status_code)
print(page.text)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
print(soup.prettify())



alpha = soup.find_all('script',{'type':'application/ld+json'})

jsonObj = json.loads(alpha[1].text)

outfile = open('c:\products.csv','w', newline='')
writer = csv.writer(outfile)
writer.writerow(["name", "type", "price", "priceCurrency", "availability" , "url"])

for item in jsonObj['itemListElement']:
    name = item['name']
    type_text = item['@type']
    url_text = item['url']
    price = item['offers']['price']
    currency = item['offers']['priceCurrency']
    availability = item['offers']['availability'].split('/')[-1]

    writer.writerow([name, type_text, price, currency, availability, url_text ])

outfile.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I could find wrong is that you have a typo in the last line - upper-case `URL` instead of lower-case `url`. Changing it made the script work perfectly.